# Query with OR excluding results in SQL

Tags: sql, mariadb

I am performing this query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS uniqueid, start
FROM sometable
LEFT JOIN log ON 
    sometable.uniqueid = log.anid AND (log.info='someinfo' or log.info='otherinfo')
WHERE `moreInfo` = 1 AND `type` = 'myType' 
  AND (`channel` LIKE 'ACHANNEL/%' or `channel` LIKE 'OTHERCHANNEL\/%')
  AND `start` > '2019-01-22 00:00:00' AND `start` < '2019-01-22 23:59:59'
GROUP BY uniqueid
```

However this part does not seem to be working:

```
AND (`channel` LIKE 'ACHANNEL%' or `channel` LIKE 'OTHERCHANNEL%')
```

I want this to give me all channels that begin with ACHANNEL/, or channel that begins with OTHERCHANNEL/, instead, it always gives me the results that begin with OTHERCHANNEL/.

The OR seems to not be working.

Any help?

Comment: @jarlh MariaDB 10.1.26

Comment: Sulejmani's answer should do. PS. Try to include some test data to see how your query actually behaves with it.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables.

Comment: When `JOINing`, you must qualify columns with the table they are in.  (Or by an alias.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query should be doing what you want.  If you are missing rows then perhaps the patterns don't really match.

I do have some suggestions though:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS t.uniqueid, MIN(start) as start
FROM sometable t LEFT JOIN
     log l
     ON t.uniqueid = l.anid AND l.info in ('someinfo', 'otherinfo')
WHERE t.`moreInfo` = 1 AND
      t.`type` = 'myType' AND
      (t.`channel` LIKE 'ACHANNEL/%' or t.`channel` LIKE 'OTHERCHANNEL/%') AND
     t.`start` > '2019-01-22' AND `start` < '2019-01-23'
GROUP BY t.uniqueid;
```

Note that I have qualified *all* column names and assumed that all column references in the `WHERE` refer to `sometable` and not `log`.  Otherwise, the `LEFT JOIN` would be turned into an `INNER JOIN`.

Notes:

- All columns are *qualified* meaning they use the table aliases.  Strongly, strongly recommended when a query has more than one table reference.
- The date arithmetic has been simplified.
- The multiple comparisons with `OR` have been simplified using `IN`.
- The "bare" `start` column has been turned into an aggregation function.
- The escape character `\` has been removed.  There is no need for any escape characters with forward slashes.

Answer (score 1):

You did not escape your first condition:

```
AND (channel LIKE 'ACHANNEL\/%' or channel LIKE 'OTHERCHANNEL\/%')
```

Comment: Except that forward slashes don't normally require an escape character.